# IE skips animate() opacity on the first attempt

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-animate, nested

I'm trying to get my jQuery animations to work properly in older versions of IE but for some reason it will skip the second .animate() process when first attempted for each div. I'm guessing it must have to do with the order of how I apply css and assign classes but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Essentially what I want to have happen is:
1. user clicks on a name/label for a customer testimonial
2. the current testimonial fades out (opacity:0)
3. the height of the testimonial's containing div adjusts to either the height of the sidebar menu or the height of target testimonial (whichever is larger)
4. the targeted testimonials fades in (opacity:1)

I have a demo page online [here](http://www.oneida-air.com/static.asp?htmltemplate=static/test/testimonials/index.html).

Here's my code:

### Javascript::

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var targetTestimonial = $('div.current');

    $('#testimonialMenu a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // disable default link behavior (no page change)                   
        targetTestimonial = $('#' + $(this).attr('rel'));

        if (!targetTestimonial.hasClass('current')){
            var tempHeight = Math.max($('#testimonialMenuMask').outerHeight(), $(targetTestimonial).outerHeight());

            $('div.current').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){
                $('#testimonialContainer').animate({height: tempHeight}, 500, function(){
                    $('div.current').removeClass('current').css({display:'none'});
                    $(targetTestimonial).css({display:'block'}).animate({opacity:1.0}, 500, function(){
                        $(this).addClass('current');
                    });
                });
            });
        }

        $('#testimonialMenu a').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

### HTML::

```
<div id="testimonialMenuMask">
    <h3>Select a Testimonial:</h3>
    <ul id="testimonialMenu">
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" rel="marianne" class="current">Marianne</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="dillon">Dillon</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="testimonialContainer">
    <div id="marianne" class="testimonialMask current">
        <!-- HTML CONTENT -- >
    </div><div id="dillon" class="testimonialMask">
        <!-- HTML CONTENT -- >
    </div>
</div>
```